# method to merge date strings not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have two methods, the first gets two time strings (one from a date picker, and the second from a time picker) and merges them into a single string like:

```
mergeTime(time, date) {
    console.log(time);
    console.log(date);
    const dateString = `${date.getDay()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
    const timeString = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}:00`;
    const merged = new Date(`${dateString} ${timeString}`);
    console.log(merged);
    return this.timestamp(merged);
}
```

Time string output:

```
Tue Apr 24 2018 15:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Date string output:

```
Thu Apr 12 2018 02:42:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

However when I merge them, I am not seeming to get the correct output:

```
Tue Apr 03 2018 15:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Finally I pass them through the last method to convert the merged time into milliseconds which seems to be working, but if you see a way i can do this differently!

```
timestamp(timeString) {
    return new Date(timeString).getTime();
}
```

Comment: Try `.toDateString()` and `toTimeString()` instead of constructing them yourselves.

Comment: yep that worked

Comment: For the record, the issue was that `getDay()` does not return 2 digit days smalleer than 10. So you'd ahve to add a leading 0 manually to get the correct string format. Same with `getMonth()`, which also ahs the additional drawback of being zerobased. So `getMonth()` for a date in January, gives you 0. These kind of things is why I try to work with UTC time and represent dates as integers.